# Show quick fix for an error in Monaco Editor

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I'm experimenting with Monaco as an editor for a custom language.

I use this code to show an example error in the [playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html) (some parts omitted):

```
const editor = monaco.editor.create(<omitted>);
const model = editor.getModel();
model.onDidChangeContent(event => {
   const value = model.getValue();
   const errors = GetErrors(value); // Implementation of GetErrors() not shown here

    monaco.editor.setModelMarkers(model, "Example", errors);
});
```

Which results in the desired error in the editor:

[image: Error hover]

**How do I make a quick fix appear for that error?** (Instead of "No quick fixes available")

I've looked at `monaco.languages.registerCodeActionProvider()` but I don't see how that ties in to the error detection code.

More generally, I've struggled to find examples for implementing Quick Fix with Monaco.

Answer (score 10):

I got it working using a Code Action Provider.

The key was to use `context.markers` inside `provideCodeActions()` to get the errors I raised elsewhere (via `setModelMarkers()`).

```
monaco.languages.registerCodeActionProvider("myLanguage", {
    provideCodeActions: (
        model /**ITextModel*/,
        range /**Range*/,
        context /**CodeActionContext*/,
        token /**CancellationToken*/
    ) => {

        const actions = context.markers.map(error => {
            return {
                title: `Example quick fix`,
                diagnostics: [error],
                kind: "quickfix",
                edit: {
                    edits: [
                        {
                            resource: model.uri,
                            edits: [
                                {
                                    range: error,
                                    text: "This text replaces the text with the error"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                isPreferred: true
            };
        });
        return {
            actions: actions,
            dispose: () => {}
        }
    }
});
```

[image: Quick fix]

Would still love to know if I'm missing an obvious source of documentation or examples for Monaco. I pieced this together using https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/index.html and [monaco.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/master/monaco.d.ts) but it took a lot of trial and error.

Comment: Thanks for this!  In case it helps anyone else, the API for Monaco is quite different from Visual Code. 

For example, the Monaco-for-JSON example at 'https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-json' uses `vscode-languageserver-types` which then requires adapting back and forth.

Comment: Did this push the quickfix change into the undo stack for you? When I press Ctrl-Z after the quick fix is applied, it is reverting to the state before the state before the quick fix. I tried setting the version ID in the edit, but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: Looks good but did not work for me without changing your innermost `edits: [{...}]` to `edit: {}` as described at https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.codeaction.html

Comment: In your code, what ties a specific quick fix to its specific error?

Comment: It must be `edit: {    edits: [{    edit: {...` since breaking API change in 0.20.0